# Crazy private memory usage when using css gradient

Tags: javascript, css, html, memory

Can someone tell me why this uses such crazy amounts of private memory? Just at page load my task manager shows 300mb, and every button click that memory goes up a huge arbitrary amount, until it crashes. Tested on chrome.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q1wLa752/

```
<div id='main-box' class="BodyGradient BodyBorder" >
    <div id="muteBox1" onclick="moveBtnDown(this)" onmouseup="moveBtnUp(this)">
        MUTE
    </div>
```

```js
var clickedFlag = false;

function moveBtnDown(btn) {
    clickedFlag = true;
    var top = $(btn).css('top');
    var left = $(btn).css('left');
    $(btn).css('top', parseInt(top) + 1);
    $(btn).css('left', parseInt(left) + 1);
}

function moveBtnUp(btn) {
    if (clickedFlag) {
        var top = $(btn).css('top');
        var left = $(btn).css('left');
        $(btn).css('top', parseInt(top) - 1)
        $(btn).css('left', parseInt(left) - 1);
        clickedFlag = false;
    }
}
```

```css
#muteBox1 {
    position: absolute;
    color: #DEDEDE;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    top:175px;
    left:45px;
    width:60px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 15%;
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    background-color: #808080;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div#main-box {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left:0px;
    right:2px;
    top:0px;
    width: 1068px;
    height: 848px;
}
.BodyGradient {
    background: #495F5F;
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0, #495F5F), color-stop(1.2, #DEDEDD));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, #495F5F 0%, #DEDEDD 120%);
}
.BodyBorder
{
    border: #DEFFFD;/* solid 0px 3px 3px 0px;*/
    border-right: #676671 solid 5px;
    border-bottom: #4F4F55 solid 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code here as requested when you tried to post the fiddle link - SO rules: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.

Comment: what s the point if the code s on jsfiddle :s

Comment: The point is this is a reference site so if in future the link to the external site is broken, people looking at this question will still understand what your problem is.  If you have looked at the help center or read the how to ask a good question:  If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Comment: my apologies, have u tried out the code? do you get the memory issue.